# What is the process called that produces characteristic X-rays?

Tags: x-rays

X-rays mostly consist of bremsstrahlung and characteristic X-rays. What is the process called that gives rise to the latter (but not the former)?

I'm trying to write a sentence like "X-rays are produced by bremsstrahlung and _______."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_x-ray) covers what is happening pretty well:

While light atoms have binding energies on order of a few $\text{eV}$, the binding energies of inner shell electrons on heavy atoms can be hundreds of $\text{eV}$. If anything happens to remove a tightly bound inner-shell electron (say a interaction with a high energy electron or other ionizing radiation), there will be a hole left deep in the atom's electron configuration.

That hole can be filled in several ways, including a having a loosely bound electron drop many levels in one step. The photon emitted by such a process will have a energy given by the difference in energies of shells and can be tens or hundreds of $\text{eV}$, well into the x-ray range.

The energy levels of the low lying states depend on the charge of the atomic nucleus, so the maximum energy photon generated this way is *characteristic* of the material.

Now, we come to the [Particle Data Book chapter "Passage of particles through matter (rev.)" (under Experimental Methods and Colliders)](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/contents_sports.html). If you look at figure 27.4 you can see several edges in the spectrum under $1\text{ MeV}$, those are the reductions in energy loss when the incident particle drops under threshold for a particular atom shell. The caption labels them as

> $\sigma_\text{p.e.}$ = Atomic photoelectric effect (electron ejection, photon absorpsion)

In truth I'm not sure that this is a term that will be correctly understood by your readers, and would suggest spending some time reading through that chapter of the PDB so see if you find a better phrase in the text. Your really problem here is that this isn't a simple processes.

Comment: The question is: What is the process _called_?

Comment: So the photoelectric effect is the cause both of characteristic X-rays (electron strikes electron in the anode of the X-ray tube) and photoelectric scattering (photon/X-ray strikes electron in the patient)?

Comment: I'm still confused: "electron ejection" seems to imply that an electron is ejected, whereas x-rays are just photons. @Qmechanic: Same goes with the Auger effect.

Comment: @nadia It's a two stage process. (1) Something kicks a electron out of a deep-shell. (2) The resulting hole is re-filled with the emission of one or more photons, and when it is just one photon the energy is in the x-ray band and characteristic of the element and shell where the hole was.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think the Auger Effect is a noise channel in this process (i.e. it will smear out the characteristic line and/or reduce the rate).

Answer (score 1):

The word that finishes your sentence would be "fluorescence". The two-step mechanism described by @dmckee where an electron is ejected, leaving a core hole which is then re-filled by another electron accompanied by the emission of a photon is correct.