# Peaks on top of Bremsstrahlung

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atoms

The following is a graph of the intensity of Bremsstrahlung generated by accelerating electrons to hit a target vs. its wavelength.

[image]

I'm wondering what causes the additional peaks for high energies? I have read in my physics script and on Wikipedia that "these peaks are characteristic of the material used as target", but what exactly is going on at the level of atoms?

Does the electron maybe go into some sort of bound state and thus loses - in addition to its kinetic energy - also some potential energy? Why would that only happen for high enough energies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bremsstrahlung spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brehmstrahlung) is a continuous spectrum because it comes from the continuous deceleration of the electron in the field of the atoms, in the case of your figure. The photons take away the energy of the decelerating electron.

There also exists a large quantum mechanical probability that the electron  scatters an  electron out from the filled  shells of the atoms in the target, [creating a hole in the shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-dispersive_X-ray_spectroscopy). The hole is filled by an electron falling  back in and releasing a photon with the [characteristic line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Spectra) for the target.The energy of these photons depend on the material and  are in the higher energy parts the more bound the ejected electron was.

Comment: Related: [What is the process called that produces characteristic X-rays?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20137/520).

Comment: Thank you for answering! This makes sense. =) Also thanks for the link, @dmckee.